# How to get Facebook friends list with birthday information?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8

As a part of a wp8 app development we need to display the Facebook friends list inside our application,For that we are using FacebookClient in wp8 .
fb.GetTaskAsync("/me/friends?fields=id,birthday"); we are using this method to get friends list mainly we need the name,id,birthday,image of every friend.but we only getting is that id and name.see the below code

```
 FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);

        fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message));
                return;
            }

            var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();

            var data = (IEnumerable<object>)result["data"]; ;


            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {


                foreach (var item in data)
                {
                    var friend = (IDictionary<string, object>)item;

                    FacebookData.Friends.Add(new Friend { Name = (string)friend["name"], id = (string)friend["id"], PictureUri = new Uri(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?type={1}&access_token={2}", (string)friend["id"], "square", App.AccessToken)) });
                }

                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/FriendSelector.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            });

        };


        fb.GetTaskAsync("/me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday");
```

Comment: That is not possible. In API v2.0 you will only get friends that are also using the app and not all friends

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: This is not possible with Graph API v2.0, because of

- `friends_*` permissions have been removed, so you can't access the friend's birthdays anymore (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions)
- `/me/friends` only shows the friends which also use your app (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids)

Answer (score -1):

Use Opengraph API to in whatever environment you use to retrieve the information. The birthday is in the user information object view below link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user

Comment: A comment would have been helpful here.  The referenced page does seem to show that the birthday is an existing parameter.